# How to build dependent dropdown menus in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, dropdown

I have three dropdown-menus, and I want a fourth one to be displayed `ONLY` if certain conditions are met (`Favourite Animal = Cat`). I also want that fourth dropdown-menu to disappear whenever the conditions are no longer true. Right now the changes are displayed if I manually save the file and execute hot reload, so I'm guessing it has something to do with `setState()`, which I have not included in the `filter.dart`-file.

File 1 - filter.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './dropdown.dart';

class Filter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterState createState() => _FilterState();
}

class _FilterState extends State<Filter> {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Container(
        height: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Dropdown('Gender', ['Female', 'Male']),
                Dropdown('Age', ['<15', '15-20', '>20']),
                Dropdown('Favourite Animal', ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster']),
                (cat) ? Dropdown('Favourite cat-toy', ['Toy-mouse', 'Ribbon', 'Ball']) : Text('')
              ],
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Submit'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

File 2 - dropdown.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _key;
  final List<String> _values;

  Dropdown(this._key, this._values);

  @override
  _DropdownState createState() => _DropdownState();
}

class _DropdownState extends State<Dropdown> {
  var _chosenValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      child: DropdownButton<String> (
        hint: Text(widget._key),
        value: _chosenValue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        iconSize: 24,
        isExpanded: true,
        items: widget._values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String value) {
          _chosenValue = value;
          (widget._key == 'Favourite Animal' && _chosenValue == 'Cat') ? cat = true : cat = false;
          setState(() {

          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool cat = false; //Feels wrong to have this bool out in the open
```

The `filter.dart`-file is called from main with `Filter()`.

Bonus question: I also want to extract the chosen values and return them to the `filter.dart`-file and use them in the `onPressed`-function in the `RaisedButton`, not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix 6 places. How about this?

```
class _FilterState extends State<Filter> {
  bool cat = false; // Move here.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Container(
        height: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Dropdown('Gender', ['Female', 'Male']),
                Dropdown('Age', ['<15', '15-20', '>20']),
                Dropdown('Favourite Animal', ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster'], update: _update), // Fix this line.
                (cat)
                    ? Dropdown(
                        'Favourite cat-toy', ['Toy-mouse', 'Ribbon', 'Ball'])
                    : Text('')
              ],
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Submit'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Add this function.
  void _update(bool b) {
    setState(() {
      cat = b;
    });
  }

}
```

```
class Dropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _key;
  final List<String> _values;
  final Function update; // Add this line.

  Dropdown(this._key, this._values, {this.update = null}); // Fix this line.

  @override
  _DropdownState createState() => _DropdownState();
}

class _DropdownState extends State<Dropdown> {
  var _chosenValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        hint: Text(widget._key),
        value: _chosenValue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        iconSize: 24,
        isExpanded: true,
        items: widget._values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String value) {
          // Fix start.
          setState(() {
            _chosenValue = value;
          });
          if (widget.update != null) {
            (widget._key == 'Favourite Animal' && _chosenValue == 'Cat')
                ? widget.update(true)
                : widget.update(false);
          }
          // Fix end.
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `DropdownButton` you have the `onChanged` callback:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
          _chosenValue = value;
          (widget._key == 'Favourite Animal' && _chosenValue == 'Cat') ? cat = true : cat = false;
          setState(() {

          });
        }
```

This call to `setState()` will be made to the Dropdown widget, not 
to the higher Filter widget.

One way to solve this would be to add to your custom Dropdown class a Function callback:

```
class Dropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _key;
  final List<String> _values;
  final Function callback;

  Dropdown(this._key, this._values, this.callback);

  @override
  _DropdownState createState() => _DropdownState();
}
```

And, in the onChanged property:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
          _chosenValue = value;
          (widget._key == 'Favourite Animal' && _chosenValue == 'Cat') ? cat = true : cat = false;
          callback();
        },
```

This will call the callback you define on the creation of Dropdown:

```
children: <Widget>[
                Dropdown('Gender', ['Female', 'Male'], callbackFunc),
                Dropdown('Age', ['<15', '15-20', '>20'], callbackFunc),
                Dropdown('Favourite Animal', ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster'], callbackFunc),
                (cat) ? Dropdown('Favourite cat-toy', ['Toy-mouse', 'Ribbon', 'Ball'], callbackFunc) : Text('')
              ],
```

Where callbackFunc may be as simple:

```
void callbackFunc(){
    setState((){});
}
```

Of course, this is not the most elegant solution.
Since you are using the callback, you can undo all the global-variable you used, and just use the callback with an argument:

```
void callbackFunc(String value){
    if (value=='cat')
        choseCat=true;
    else
        choseCat=false;
    setState((){});
}
```

Also, you don't have to check the widget key to verify which dropdown is being called. You can check if the callback is null before calling it, and only give the callback function to the appropriate ones:

```
children: <Widget>[
                Dropdown('Gender', ['Female', 'Male']),
                Dropdown('Age', ['<15', '15-20', '>20']),
                Dropdown('Favourite Animal', ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster'], callbackFunc),
                (cat) ? Dropdown('Favourite cat-toy', ['Toy-mouse', 'Ribbon', 'Ball']) : Text('')
              ],

[...]

onChanged: (String value) {
          _chosenValue = value;
          (widget._key == 'Favourite Animal' && _chosenValue == 'Cat') ? cat = true : cat = false;
          if (callback)
              callback();
        },
```

Don't forget to make the callback optional in this case:

```
Dropdown({@required this._key, @required this._values, this.callback});
```

I'm sure many other optimizations may be done with this approach. And with bigger apps other [State management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) should be chosen to make your life easier.